# Kensington trackball button

Tags: identification, button, mouse

I'm looking for replacement button for Kensingtons "Orbit Trackball with Scroll Ring". I'm hoping to find at least something similar.
Here is how the original button looks like:

### [image: Kensingtons trackball button]

**Button dimensions**

- Width: 6.2mm
- Depth: 6.2mm
- Height: 7.3mm
- Height (pressed): 6.8mm
- Pin size: 0.7mm
- Distance between pins: 4.8mm

There is symbols on top (can see on photo): 'J' and '2'. On the bottom "F3" and "TTC". It is possible to bent pins the way, that they will be sticking at one side, so button could be used as SMD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know that this posting is a "shopping" type question and falls outside the normal design type questions accepted here. But I know the frustration that can occur when a favorite mouse starts to get really flakey and the buttons lose their click!!

This particular type of switch is commonly used in various types of computer mice and track ball units. I have replaced many of the same type in mice that have become old favorites but used so much that the switches simply wore out. Here is the replacement unit in the Mouser catalog.

[image]

[image]

I purchased my replacement switches in quantity at the time of ordering a few years ago and have used them to repair at least three models of computer mouse.

Comment: Thank you for fast response! Hopefully soon will bring up to life my trackball. :)